# JavaBridge return 404 error on tomcat

Tags: java, php, php-java-bridge

I want To use PHP / Javabridge. I downloaded JavaBridge.war and copied it into webapp directory off tomcat8 server. but when i start tomcat server and type this url:

```
http://localhost:8080/JavaBridge/
```

I ge Foliwing Error

```
HTTP Status 404 - /JavaBridge/
```

I cannot understand whats the problem is, or how can i debug this?

Comment: Well JavaBridge is not found, you have to debug and find out why..

Comment: I am new in tomcat server and java, how can i debug?